# Изменение Background у элементов ListView в зависимости от значения. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

У меня есть `ListView` отображающий список файлов. При добавлении в `ListView` предметов, `background` у добавленного элемента должен быть красным, так как изначально у добавленных файлов `MessageFileId == null`. Потом для какого либо элемента я меняю `MessageFileId` на какое либо значение. И когда `MessageFileId != null`, нужно что бы `background` у этого элемента стал зеленым. Как такое сделать? На данный момент все элементы имеют только `background` красного цвета.

**ViewModel:**

```
public class TicketAttachFiles
{
    public string AttachFilePath { get; set; }

    public int? MessageFileId { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<TicketAttachFiles> AttachFiles { get; set; }
```

**Viev:**

```
<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AttachFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" d:DataContext="{Binding AttachFiles, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TicketMessageFileId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <fa:ImageAwesome Icon="PictureOutline" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                           Text="{Binding Path=AttachFilePath}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

После того как я для какого либо элемента установлю значение поля `MessageFileId`, у этого элемента не пропадает фон красного цвета.

Comment: Потому что у вас простое свойство. View не будет видеть его изменения без INPC. Ну а вообще тут вроде можно обойтись одним конвертером.

Comment: Также внутри `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` вся привязка работает с главной VM, а не с VM текущего `ListViewItem`. Перенесите триггер внутрь `DataTemplate` (который внутри `ListView.ItemTemplate`) и уже там меняйте что вам угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вам стоит запомнить одно простое правило.
   Если вы меняете значение привязанного свойства из кода и хотите отслеживать это изменение во View слое, то это свойство должно обязательно вызывать `INotifyPropertyChanged` (INPC)!

   - То есть вы создаете где то класс, который будет реализовывать INPC.
     Самый простой пример:

     ```
     public class BaseVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
         public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
         {
             PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
         }
     }
     ```
   - Далее вы свой класс VM наследуете от ранее созданного класса:

     ```
     class TicketAttachFiles : BaseVM
     ```
   - И во всех необходимых свойствах вызываете метод оповещения, делая что то вроде:

     ```
     private int? messageFileId;
     public int? MessageFileId
     {
         get => messageFileId;
         set
         {
             messageFileId = value;
             RaisePropertyChanged();
         }
     }
     ```
2. В данной строке `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TicketMessageFileId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">` ваша ошибка заключается в том, что свойство `TicketMessageFileId` будет искаться в главной VM (там, где у вас `AttachFiles`). Для грамотной работы триггер стоит поместить в `DataTemplate` самого шаблона.
   Разметка будет примерно следующей:

   ```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AttachFiles}" >
       <ListView.ItemsPanel>
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
               <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
           </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemsPanel>
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding AttachFilePath}"/>
               <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MessageFileId}" Value="{x:Null}">
                       <Setter TargetName="TextBlock" Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red"/>
                   </DataTrigger>
               </DataTemplate.Triggers>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
   </ListView>
   ```

---

Результат:

[image: Result]