# Как покрасить Строки DataGrid MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Нужно покрасить строки DataGrid зависимости от условия  в методе `IsValidName()`. Для покраски был создан конвертер по имени  `RowToBrushConverter` конвертора унаследован от базового  `ConverterBase`.
В свойстве  `DataGrid.RowStyle` задаю  стиль для `DataGridRow` где  буду изменять цвет строки.

**Проблема:** в том что  красит  частично и только при скроллинге **DataGrid**.

**Как должно работать:** если условие верно `IsValidName()` красит в белый цвет если нет тогда красный.

**DataGrid.RowStyle**

```
           <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTip}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource RowToBrush}}"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**ConverterBase**

```
    abstract class ConverterBase : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);
        public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;
    }
```

**RowToBrushConverter**

```
    class RowToBrushConverter : ConverterBase
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(Brush))
            {
                return null;
            }
            var FileName = (FileName)value;
            return !FileName.IsValidName() ? Brushes.Red : Brushes.White;
        }
    }
```

**FileName**

```
public class FileName:ModelBase
    {
        private System.IO.FileInfo Info;
        private string Directory;
        

        private string original;
        public string Original
        {
            get { return original; }
            set 
            { 
                original = value;
                OriginalImage = GetBitmapSource(GetIcon());
                OnPropertyChanged("Original");
            }
        }
        private BitmapSource originalImage;
        public BitmapSource OriginalImage
        {
            get { return originalImage; }
            set
            {
                originalImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OriginalImage");
            }
        }


        private string modified;
        public string Modified
        {
            get { return modified; }
            set
            {
                modified = value;
                ModifiedImage = GetBitmapSource(GetIconModified());
                OnPropertyChanged("Modified");
                
                
            }
        }

        public BitmapSource modifiedImage;
        public BitmapSource ModifiedImage
        {
            get { return modifiedImage; }
            set
            {
                modifiedImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ModifiedImage");
            }
        }

        public string toolTip { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip
        {
            get { return toolTip; }
            set
            {
                toolTip = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToolTip");
            }
        }


       



        public BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap
            (
                bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
            );

            return bitmapSource;
        }



        //Название каталога не должно заканчиваться\
        public FileName(string directory, string original, string modified)
        {
            Directory = directory.TrimEnd('\\');

            Original = original;
            Modified = modified;
            ToolTip= ParentDirectory() + @"\"+ Original;
           
        }
        

        public FileName(FileName name, bool swap = false)
        {
            Directory = name.Directory.TrimEnd('\\');

            Original = name.Original;
            Modified = name.Modified;

            if (swap) Swap();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Modified = Original;
        }

        public bool IsValidName()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Modified))
            {
                return false;
            }

            bool result = Modified.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) == -1;
            return result;
        }

        public void Swap()
        {
            var temp = Original;
            Original = Modified;
            Modified = temp;
        }

        public string GetExtension()
        {
            return Path.GetExtension(Original);
        }

        public string GetModifiedNameWithoutExtension()
        {
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Modified);
        }

        public string ParentDirectory()
        {
            var parts = Directory.Split('\\');
            return parts[parts.Length - 1];
        }

        public string FullPath()
        {
            return Directory + "\\" + Original;
        }

        public string FullPathModified(string newDirectory = null)
        {
            if (newDirectory != null) return newDirectory + "\\" + Modified;
            return Directory + "\\" + Modified;
        }

       

        public Bitmap GetIcon()
        {
            return Common.ShellIcon.GetBitmapIcon(FullPath());
        }

        public Bitmap GetIconModified()
        {
            return Common.ShellIcon.GetBitmapIcon(FullPathModified());
        }

        private void LoadFileInfo()
        {
            if (Info == null)
                Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.FullPath());
        }

        public string CreationDate()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            return Info.CreationTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + Info.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString();
        }

        public string LastWriteDate()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            return Info.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + Info.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString();
        }

        //trim file length to fit a unit
        private double TrimSize(double length, int n = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) length /= 1024.0;         //divide n times by 1024            
            return Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(length), 2);     //convert to double and round to 2 decimal places
        }

        public string ReadableFileSize()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            long length = Info.Length;

            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 1)) return length + " B";               //lower than 1kb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 2)) return TrimSize(length, 1) + " KB"; //lower than 1mb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 3)) return TrimSize(length, 2) + " MB"; //lower than 1gb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 4)) return TrimSize(length, 3) + " GB"; //lower than 1tb

            return length + " TB";                                              //return size in tb    
        }
    }
```

### Как работает

Когда я делаю имена файлов " ",все равно некоторые строки не окрашиваться и если я скроллить не буду окраска не будет совсем происходить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Как должно работать

Если имена файлов не " "
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если имена файлов  " "
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы делаете много лишнего. Сделайте **свойство**, публичное, которое будет вызывать INPC, пусть это будет `bool`. Далее, в `set` того свойства, к которому надо применять эту проверку (имя?), добавляйте вызов вашей логики проверки, чтоб она изменила значение `bool` свойства. Все, дальше просто сделайте триггер, который задаст цвет элементу.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Как я понял например сделать свойство  `IsValidName` и конвертировать потом из bool в цвет чтобы покрасить строку.

Comment: Зачем вам конвертировать что либо? Я ведь сказал "триггер", цвет - это обязанность View слоя, XAML, вот пусть он и разбирается что ему выводить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я понял, какой  триггер есть в `DataGridRow` когда метаться строка ?

Comment: Зачем вам `триггер когда метаться строка DataGridRow`? Вы явно меня не поняли. У вас должно быть свойство `bool IsValidName`, которое вызывает INPC (обновление интерфейса), в XAML у вас должен быть триггер, который привязан к этому свойству, что-то на подобии `<Style.Triggers><DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding IsValidName}" Value = "true"><Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/></DataTrigger></Style.Triggers>`, все, это все решение вашей задачи. При изменении `IsValidName`, будет меняться и цвет (`True = Red`, `False = default`).

Comment: Вот вам два примера: [простой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/947701/220553), [c анимацией](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154540/220553). Оба используют один и тот же принцип, который нужен и вам. Заметьте, ни единого конвертора и цвета в коде, лишь привязки и XAML.

Comment: Cпасибо за потраченное время  сейчас буду разбираться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отдельное спасибо за наставленные  **EvgeniyZ**.

**DataGrid.RowStyle**

```
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTip}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding = "{Binding IsValidNameFile}" Value = "true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

**FileName**

```
public class FileName:ModelBase
    {
        private System.IO.FileInfo Info;
        private string Directory;
        

        private string original;
        public string Original
        {
            get { return original; }
            set 
            { 
                original = value;
                OriginalImage = GetBitmapSource(GetIcon());
                OnPropertyChanged("Original");
            }
        }
        private BitmapSource originalImage;
        public BitmapSource OriginalImage
        {
            get { return originalImage; }
            set
            {
                originalImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("OriginalImage");
            }
        }


        private string modified;
        public string Modified
        {
            get { return modified; }
            set
            {
                modified = value;
                ModifiedImage = GetBitmapSource(GetIconModified());
                OnPropertyChanged("Modified");
                IsValidNameFile = !IsValidName();
            }
        }

        private BitmapSource modifiedImage;
        public BitmapSource ModifiedImage
        {
            get { return modifiedImage; }
            set
            {
                modifiedImage = value;


                OnPropertyChanged("ModifiedImage");
            }
        }

        private string toolTip { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip
        {
            get { return toolTip; }
            set
            {
                toolTip = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToolTip");
            }
        }


        private bool isValidNamefile;
        public bool IsValidNameFile
        {
            get
            {
                return isValidNamefile;
            }
            set
            {
                isValidNamefile = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsValidNameFile");
            }
        }





        public BitmapSource GetBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap
            (
                bitmap.GetHbitmap(),
                IntPtr.Zero,
                Int32Rect.Empty,
                BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions()
            );

            return bitmapSource;
        }



        //Название каталога не должно заканчиваться\
        public FileName(string directory, string original, string modified)
        {
            Directory = directory.TrimEnd('\\');

            Original = original;
            Modified = modified;
            ToolTip= ParentDirectory() + @"\"+ Original;
           
        }
        

        public FileName(FileName name, bool swap = false)
        {
            Directory = name.Directory.TrimEnd('\\');

            Original = name.Original;
            Modified = name.Modified;

            if (swap) Swap();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Modified = Original;
        }

        public bool IsValidName()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Modified)|| string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Modified)) return false;
            return Modified.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) == -1;
        }

        public void Swap()
        {
            var temp = Original;
            Original = Modified;
            Modified = temp;
        }

        public string GetExtension()
        {
            return Path.GetExtension(Original);
        }

        public string GetModifiedNameWithoutExtension()
        {
            return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Modified);
        }

        public string ParentDirectory()
        {
            var parts = Directory.Split('\\');
            return parts[parts.Length - 1];
        }

        public string FullPath()
        {
            return Directory + "\\" + Original;
        }

        public string FullPathModified(string newDirectory = null)
        {
            if (newDirectory != null) return newDirectory + "\\" + Modified;
            return Directory + "\\" + Modified;
        }

       

        public Bitmap GetIcon()
        {
            return Common.ShellIcon.GetBitmapIcon(FullPath());
        }

        public Bitmap GetIconModified()
        {
            return Common.ShellIcon.GetBitmapIcon(FullPathModified());
        }

        private void LoadFileInfo()
        {
            if (Info == null)
                Info = new System.IO.FileInfo(this.FullPath());
        }

        public string CreationDate()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            return Info.CreationTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + Info.CreationTime.ToShortTimeString();
        }

        public string LastWriteDate()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            return Info.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString() + " " + Info.LastWriteTime.ToShortTimeString();
        }

        //trim file length to fit a unit
        private double TrimSize(double length, int n = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) length /= 1024.0;         //divide n times by 1024            
            return Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(length), 2);     //convert to double and round to 2 decimal places
        }

        public string ReadableFileSize()
        {
            LoadFileInfo();

            long length = Info.Length;

            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 1)) return length + " B";               //lower than 1kb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 2)) return TrimSize(length, 1) + " KB"; //lower than 1mb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 3)) return TrimSize(length, 2) + " MB"; //lower than 1gb
            if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 4)) return TrimSize(length, 3) + " GB"; //lower than 1tb

            return length + " TB";                                              //return size in tb    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Несколько замечаний на будущее: `private string toolTip { get; set; }` - если вы переопределяете `get` и `set`, то лучше вам нужен некий объект, который будет источником данных. Если этот объект не используется за пределами класса и для него не надо ограничивать доступ (только чтение например), то лучше использовать приватные поля, как вы например это сделали с `Modified`. Далее, если свойство, обновляется **через UI** (пользователь написал что-то), то INPC вызывать не нужно, достаточно простого `public int Val {get;set;}`, но если обновляется **через код**, то уже для обновления UI нужен INPC

Comment: Метод `string ReadableFileSize()` я думаю у вас вовсе лишний, переопределите `ToString`. Портянку из `if (length < Math.Pow(1024, 1))` можно (и нужно) переделать на современный `switch`, язык обновляется, следите за обновлениями, это может сильно сэкономить вам времени! Всякие `Convert.ToDouble` - уже давно устарели, используйте `тип.Parse` или `тип.TryParse`. `length + " B"` => `"{length} B"`. Вызов постоянно `LoadFileInfo()` такая себе затея. `Directory + "\\" + Original` (и аналогично) лучше делать через `Path.Combine`. А так молодцы, что справились с задачей)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Cпасибо за помощь и за review кода. Я очень благодарен за потраченное время.

Comment: Еще вопрос у меня `Model` есть логика это не нарушает правила `MVVM`? Может вынести ее в отдельный класс.

Comment: Ну давайте порассуждаем, что такое MVVM? Это деление проекта на слабо связанные друг с другом слои, где M - это данные (работа с базой, чтение файла, отправка запросов на сайт и др.), то есть слой, который хранит и обрабатывает в себе данные проекта. V - это интерфейс (UI), все кнопочки, анимации, цвета, окна и так далее. VM - связующий слой, который берет из M нужные данные, формирует публичные свойства для привязки, а также обрабатывает команды от UI. Вот теперь посмотрите на свой код и скажите, ваша логика к какому слою относится?

Comment: Я бы весь ваш код вынес в M слой, который бы собирал и хранил в себе нужные данные, размер пусть будет просто числом (байты), а в VM я лишь дергал бы нужные методы и выводил байты в нужном формате. Но помните, что MVVM, это лишь набор рекомендаций, хотите, следуйте им, хотите, нарушайте, вы создатель своего проекта, не загоняйте себя в рамки, делайте как удобно (в рамках разумного конечно). А вообще, если прям хотите "жести", то можете посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817), там весьма удобный подход модульного MVVM проекта, который легко проектируется и расширяется.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Cпасибо за информацию. Это очень полезная инфа думаю еще кому-то пригодиться кто прочитает эту пост)